# Method with type parameter to return array of said type

Tags: c#, generics, constructor, activator

I am trying to create a generic method in C# that will return an array of the specified type. This is what my method looks like at the moment:

```
private T[] GetKeys<T>(string key, Dictionary<string, object> obj) where T : new()
{
    if (obj.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        object[] objs = (object[])obj[key];
        T[] list = new T[objs.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < objs.Length; i++)
        {
            list[i] = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(
                             typeof(T),
                             new object[] {
                                 (Dictionary<string, object>)objs[i] 
                             });
        }
        return list;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

As this class is used internally, and is not available by using the library I already know what classes will be put into the `<T>`. All the classes have the same parameters in their contructors. But I had to give them a public contructor with no parameters before this code would even compile. Now when I get to the `Activator.CreateInstance` line I get an error saying `Constructor on type 'MyNamespace.MyClass+MyOtherClass' not found`. `MyClass` is the class that contains the method above. `MyOtherClass` is the class that is passed in as `T`.

Any help would be appreciated Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you as long as your constructor looks like this:

```
public MyType (Dictionary<string,object> dict)
{
}
```

If your constructors are non-public, you'll need to alter GetConstructor to pass in BindingFlags.NonPublic.

```
        private T[] GetKeys<T>(string key, Dictionary<string, object> obj)
        // Since you're not using the default constructor don't need this:
        //   where T : new()
        {
            if (obj.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                object[] objs = (object[])obj[key];
                T[] list = new T[objs.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < objs.Length; i++)
                {
                    list[i] = (T)typeof(T).GetConstructor(new [] {typeof(Dictionary<string,object>)}).Invoke (new object[] {
                                         (Dictionary<string, object>)objs[i] 
                                     });
                }
                return list;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ideally I would like the constructor to be internal. However, I'm not comfortable with how to use the additional parameters required for GetConstructor so I think I'll just opt for the public contructor at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Your GetKeys<T> requires that [T must have a public parameterless constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

```
private T[] GetKeys<T>(...) where T : new()
                                       ↑
```

This constrained on T allows you to write code like this in the method body:

```
T t = new T();
```

Since you're not using this but expect a certain other constructor (which cannot be enforced like a public parameterless constructor), just remove the constraint and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are building similarities into the classes for the sake of this method it would probably be best just to have them all extend the same interface (or inherit the same base class, whatever is appropriate for your application). Then you'll just need to use the constructor parameters you pass in to build up a list of the base class. Then in the calling code you can cast the list items as appropriate.

Comment: Unfortunately the contructor is where the similarities between these classes stop. They are passed in a Dictionary object which will have completely different keys for each run of this method. The classes also have no similar properties or methods. The constructors for each class check and handle the dictionary differntly.